# are the numbers stored as strings in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am loading my sql data tables into it and wish to get results depending upon various requirements. I am having a problem in rangequery. When I am writing this:

```
$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/sample/new/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{ query:{range:{price_incl_tax:{gte:1000,lte:1500}}} }'
```

the results where `price_incl_tax=140.0000` as well as `13500.0000` are also coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `price_incl_tax` seems to be stored as a string. It probably happend because the `price_incl_tax` field was initially added as a string instead of a number. You can verify field types in your index by running

`$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/sample/new/_mapping?pretty=true'`

Elasticsearch allows you to control individual field types by specifying [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/) during index or type creation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was exactly the problem.

Comment: I would also like to know if the mapping can be updated or it has to be recreated all over again.

Comment: In general, you can only add new fields to an existing mapping. A field type of an existing field cannot be changed. So, in your case you will have to recreate the index.